# How to build a hybrid_method that counts the number of records from the last X days?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a table of tennis matches and I would like to create a query field that counts the number of previous matches within a date range of the date of the focal match. For example:

```
+----------+------------+---------------------------+
| match_id |    date    | num_matches within 3 days |
+----------+------------+---------------------------+
|        1 | 01/01/2020 |                         0 |
|        2 | 02/01/2020 |                         1 |
|        3 | 03/01/2020 |                         2 |
|        4 | 05/01/2020 |                         2 |
|        5 | 05/01/2020 |                         3 |
|        6 | 10/01/2020 |                         0 |
+----------+------------+---------------------------+
```

I've tried using a correlated sub-query as set out [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#correlated-subquery-relationship-hybrid) but I can't figure out how to create the conditions:

```
@hybrid_method
def match_count(self, timespan_days):
    cut_off = self.date_time_inferred - timedelta(days=timespan_days)
    return sum(x >= cut_off and <some_cond_for_less_than_current_match_date> for x in self.date_time_inferred)

@match_count.expression
def match_count(cls, timespan_days):
    cut_off = cls.date_time_inferred - timedelta(days=timespan_days)
    return (
        select(func.count(cls.date_time_inferred)).
        where(
            and_(
                cls.date_time_inferred.__ge__(cut_off),
                cls.date_time_inferred.__lt__(<not_sure_what_goes_here>),
            )
        ).label('match_count')
    )
```

In trialling simpler forms of the above I also kept getting the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: columns argument to select() must be a Python list or other iterable
```

On the code:

```
select(func.count(cls.date))
```

So I'm clearly doing a whole heap of stuff wrong.

Hopefully someone can help me understand how to fix this? Also very open to different ways to accomplish the same thing. I would like to stick with a hybrid attribute though...

Comment: Your link points to the 1.4 docs.  Are you using 1.4 (currently in beta)?  If not, use the docs for the version that you are using: 1.4 contains significant changes.

Comment: I'm using 1.3 - thanks for the heads up - will correct the link. Looks like correlated sub queries are the same in both 1.3 and 1.4 though.

Comment: If you look closely you'll see that it's `select(...)` in 1.4 but `select([...])` in 1.3 (hence the error message you see).

Comment: Ahhhhh! Well that solves part 1 of my problems - thank you :) Any hints on how to tackle the mess I've got myself into with the conditions? I can't figure out how to find the date of the current match so I can write a less than condition...

Answer (score 1):

Below is the (almost) full code snippet:

```
# ... omitted import statements and session configuration

def _date(date_str):
    return datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d")


class Match(Base):
    __tablename__ = "match"

    match_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(Date, nullable=False)

    @hybrid_method
    def match_count(self, timespan_days):
        cut_off = self.date - timedelta(days=timespan_days)
        sess = object_session(self)
        M = Match
        q = (
            sess.query(M)
            # .filter(M.match_id != self.match_id)  # option-1: only other on the same day
            .filter(M.match_id < self.match_id)  # option-2: only smaller-id on the same day (as in OP)
            .filter(M.date <= self.date)
            .filter(M.date >= cut_off)
        )
        return q.count()

    @match_count.expression
    def match_count(cls, timespan_days):
        M = aliased(Match, name="other")
        cut_off = cls.date - timespan_days
        q = (
            select([func.count(M.match_id)])
            # .filter(Match.match_id != self.match_id)  # option-1: only other on the same day
            .where(M.match_id < cls.match_id)  # option-2: only smaller-id on the same day (as in OP)
            .where(M.date <= cls.date)
            .where(M.date >= cut_off)
        )
        return q.label("match_count")


def test():
    Base.metadata.drop_all()
    Base.metadata.create_all()

    from sys import version_info as py_version
    from sqlalchemy import __version__ as sa_version

    print(f"PY version={py_version}")
    print(f"SA version={sa_version}")
    print(f"SA engine={engine.name}")
    print("=" * 80)

    # 1. test data
    matches = [
        Match(date=_date("2020-01-01")),
        Match(date=_date("2020-01-02")),
        Match(date=_date("2020-01-03")),
        Match(date=_date("2020-01-05")),
        Match(date=_date("2020-01-05")),
        Match(date=_date("2020-01-10")),
    ]
    session.add_all(matches)
    session.commit()
    print("=" * 80)

    # 2. test query in "in-memory"
    for m in session.query(Match):
        print(m, m.match_count(3))
    print("=" * 80)

    # 3. test query on "SQL"
    session.expunge_all()
    q = session.query(Match, Match.match_count(3))
    for match, match_count in q:
        print(match, match_count)
    print("=" * 80)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

The code above produces the following output:

```
============================================================
PY version=sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=1, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
SA version=1.3.20
SA engine=postgresql
============================================================
<Match(date=datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), match_id=1)> 0
<Match(date=datetime.date(2020, 1, 2), match_id=2)> 1
<Match(date=datetime.date(2020, 1, 3), match_id=3)> 2
<Match(date=datetime.date(2020, 1, 5), match_id=4)> 2
<Match(date=datetime.date(2020, 1, 5), match_id=5)> 3
<Match(date=datetime.date(2020, 1, 10), match_id=6)> 0
============================================================
<Match(date=datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), match_id=1)> 0
<Match(date=datetime.date(2020, 1, 2), match_id=2)> 1
<Match(date=datetime.date(2020, 1, 3), match_id=3)> 2
<Match(date=datetime.date(2020, 1, 5), match_id=4)> 2
<Match(date=datetime.date(2020, 1, 5), match_id=5)> 3
<Match(date=datetime.date(2020, 1, 10), match_id=6)> 0
============================================================
```

whereas the query `q` would like like below (in `postgresql`):

```
SELECT match.match_id,
       match.date,

  (SELECT count(other.match_id) AS count_1
   FROM match AS other
   WHERE other.match_id < match.match_id
     AND other.date <= match.date
     AND other.date >= match.date - %(date_1)s) AS match_count
FROM match
```

One item i would like to point out is that the "in-memory" check is not very efficient, because one has to query the database for each `Match` instance. Therefore, I would use the last query if possible.

Comment: Ah of course - use an alias and count that :) Thanks a million! Will test this out tomorrow!

Comment: Hey. Just been working through this. What is the `object_session` method called in `sess = object_session(self)`? Presumably that's a way of creating a `session` in order to perform the query? I usually have a Data Access Layer class that creates the `session` and I use this to generate queries. How would I do things differently now I'm querying from within a table class?

Comment: Run into an issue with the above. Posted this as a new question because my hunch is that it might be an issue with MySQL vs PostgreSQL...

Comment: Figured out what `object_session` was. For anyone else reading this - https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.object_session