# How to subtract a number of days from a date?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I've been trying to build a hybrid method that contains a query to count the number of previous records within a certain time frame. My original post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64986150/11277108) and the answer I'm trying to work from is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65060988/11277108).

I've refined an MRE from the answer:

```
class DataAccessLayer():

    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = create_engine(CONN_STRING)
        self.connection = self.engine.connect()
        Session = sessionmaker()
        Session.configure(bind=self.engine)
        self.session = Session()
        Base.metadata.drop_all(self.engine)
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)


class Match(Base):
    __tablename__ = "match_overall"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "test", "extend_existing": True}

    match_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    match_date = Column(DateTime, index=True)

    @hybrid_method
    def match_count(self, timespan_days):
        M = Match
        cut_off = self.match_date - timedelta(days=timespan_days)
        q = (
            self.dal.session.query(M)
            .filter(M.match_date <= self.match_date)
            .filter(M.match_date >= cut_off)
        )
        return q.count()

    @match_count.expression
    def match_count(cls, timespan_days):
        M = aliased(Match, name="other")
        cut_off = cls.match_date - timedelta(days=timespan_days)
        q = (
            select([func.count(M.match_id)])
            .where(M.match_date <= cls.match_date)
            .where(M.match_date >= cut_off)
        )
        return q.label("match_count")


dal = DataAccessLayer()
matches = [
    Match(match_id=1, match_date=datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0)),
    Match(match_id=2, match_date=datetime(2020, 1, 2, 0, 0)),
    Match(match_id=3, match_date=datetime(2020, 1, 3, 0, 0)),
    Match(match_id=4, match_date=datetime(2020, 1, 5, 0, 0)),
    Match(match_id=5, match_date=datetime(2020, 1, 5, 0, 0)),
    Match(match_id=6, match_date=datetime(2020, 1, 10, 0, 0)),
]
dal.session.add_all(matches)
dal.session.commit()

qry = dal.session.query(Match.match_id, Match.match_count(3)) # count num matches in last three days
for match_id, match_count in qry:
    print(match_id, match_count)
```

The query should be returning:

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 4
6 1
```

However, it returns:

```
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 2
5 2
6 1
```

Which is basically a count of the number of matches on a particular day - it's not counting previous matches within the specified timeframe.

The SQL that's generated from the above is:

```
SELECT test.match_overall.match_id AS test_match_overall_match_id, (SELECT count(other.match_id) AS count_1 
FROM test.match_overall AS other
WHERE other.match_date <= test.match_overall.match_date AND other.match_date >= test.match_overall.match_date - %(match_date_1)s) AS match_count
FROM test.match_overall
```

I think the issue might be that MySQL doesn't understand the following snippet:

```
other.match_date >= test.match_overall.match_date - %(match_date_1)s) AS match_count
```

Reading around the subject the SQL way of writing this would be:

```
other.match_date >= DATE_SUB(test.match_overall.match_date INTERVAL %(match_date_1)s DAY) AS match_count
```

However, I can't work out how to create this using SQLAlchemy.

Any help to point me in the right direction would be much appreciated...

Comment: related: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5672

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - I learnt about `sa.text` today :-) I'll make sure I test out the `synchronize_session=False` too

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this is to use the `text` method via:

```
from sqlalchemy import text
```

This enables you to write out the `INTERVAL` text as follows:

```
@match_count.expression
def match_count(cls, time_frame_days):
    M = aliased(Match, name="other")
    q = (
        select([func.count(M.match_id)])
        .where(M.match_date <= cls.match_date)
        .where(M.match_date >= func.date_sub(
            cls.match_date, text(f"INTERVAL {time_frame_days} DAY"))
        )
    )
    return q.label("match_count")
```